# Cannot ssh into server

Tags: macos, ssh

I am trying to SSH into a linux machine running ubuntu, but the interactive shell stuck somewhere and I can't key in anything. I am on Mac OS X Lion. This only happens when I am trying to access via an external IP. Local LAN SSH is working perfectly.

```
macbook:~ user$ ssh -v -v user@serverip
// i skipped the rest of the log, but I can paste it here again if needed.

Authenticated to serverip
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

My terminal shell just hang after this, and I can't key in anything. I checked var/log/auth on the server and saw that the a session is being created and I had already logged in, but I don't see any responses on my client machine.

I googled around and a lot of the solution had to do with the Broadcom wireless driver, but I am not even using one, so I am pretty clueless here.

To give you more information, the linux machine is also running a web server, and I have no problem accessing the web server.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to ssh to this machine in the past? Are you able to connect to this machine via http or other protocols? Are you able to connect via ssh from a different client?

Comment: I was able to ssh to this machine, and I am able to connect to this machine via http. Tried with another Window machine, can't work as well.

Comment: Is your local network behind a router? If so, to access a local machine from an external IP, you'll need to setup a port forward for port 22 on the router to port 22 on your internal SSH host.

Comment: @JohnWatson. Port forwarding done. But still can't connect

Answer (score 0):

Revolver,

Some things to try:

1. Move the web server off the port that works (I'm guessing Apache..?).
2. Then make the SSH server listen to the working port that you used for your webserver. (you may need restart each respective daemon.
3. report results.

(I'm trying to rule out the possibility that your ISP is blocking the connection..)

Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a "ProxyCommand nc %h %p" in ~/.ssh/config

**UPDATE**

I have been experiencing a similar problem ever since I updated to Mac OS X Mountain Lion. However, a combination of Mac OS X (stock ssh client) and Asus Router and external server (over WAN) causes login to timeout, for me.

If I try to connect using my Mobile hot-spot (skip Asus Router) to same host, connection works fine and I am able to use interactive terminal.

If I try to connect using Asus Router to local server Local (LAN), it works.

If I use Forklift (SFTP/SCP)/Chrome SSH Client/putty, Asus Router and external server, it works.

But stock ssh, Asus Router and external server, doesn't work. But, this is my normal setup and has to "just work".

There is a long thread on apple forum about this - [Broken SSH client on Mavericks](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5603603)

After reading this thread, I used above command in ssh config, and I am able to work with my "normal setup".

Comment: Can you explain your answer? It helps to give some background explanation when answering a question.